# Yii how to import a widget code in console

Tags: php, yii

I'm trying to reuse some code written in a widget for cron e-mailing. I put this part in my view but gives me an error

```
$this->widget('ShortProfileWidget', array('shortProfileFor'=>'Email')); 


exception 'CException' with message 'DailyEmailCommand and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "widget".' in C:\wamp\yii\framework\base\CComponent.php:265
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the default import list of YII console.php in config folder

```
'import'=>array(
    'application.models.*',
    'application.components.*',
    'application.extensions.*',
),
```

add your widgets here...

```
'import'=>array(
    'application.models.*',
    'application.components.*',
    'application.extensions.*',
    'application.widgets.*',
),
```